# JavaScript date method not working in FireFox

Tags: javascript, date, vue.js, timer, countdown

I've built a countdown timer for a website and it works fine on other browsers but for some reason, the way I've built it doesn't seem to work on firefox and I'm not sure why. The numbers on the page say NaN while on other browsers, the numbers actually countdown. My code for this is below, any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
<template>
  <div class="countdown">
    <!-- <img class="cover-image" src="@/assets/img/event_cover_image@2x.png" /> -->
    <div class="countdown-container">
      <h2>{{ `${$t('countdown.labels.countdownToEvent')}:` }}</h2>
      <div class="counter">
        <div>
          <div id="day">0</div>
          {{ $t('countdown.labels.days') }}
        </div>
        <div>
          <div id="hour">0</div>
          {{ $t('countdown.labels.hours') }}
        </div>
        <div>
          <div id="minute">0</div>
          {{ $t('countdown.labels.minutes') }}
        </div>
        <div>
          <div id="second">0</div>
          {{ $t('countdown.labels.seconds') }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Countdown',
  data() {
    return {
      countDate: new Date('Oct 20, 2020 00:00:00:00').getTime(),
      counter: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.counter = setInterval(() => {
      const now = new Date().getTime();
      const gap = this.countDate - now;

      const second = 1000;
      const minute = second * 60;
      const hour = minute * 60;
      const day = hour * 24;

      let d = Math.floor(gap / day);
      let h = Math.floor((gap % day) / hour);
      let m = Math.floor((gap % hour) / minute);
      let s = Math.floor((gap % minute) / second);

      if (d <= 0 && h <= 0 && m <= 0 && s <= 0) {
        clearInterval(this.counter);
        d = 0;
        h = 0;
        m = 0;
        s = 0;
      }
      document.querySelector('#day').innerText = d;
      document.querySelector('#hour').innerText = h;
      document.querySelector('#minute').innerText = m;
      document.querySelector('#second').innerText = s;
    }, 1000);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.counter);
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Debug and see what is different. console.log() is your friend. console.log(this.countDate); console.log(gap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date):

> **dateString**
> A string value representing a date, specified in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method.

And then [`parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> It is **not recommended to use Date.parse** as until ES5, parsing of strings was entirely implementation dependent. There are still many differences in how different hosts parse date strings, therefore date strings should be manually parsed (a library can help if many different formats are to be accommodated).

---

And that is your problem. Different implementations support different date formats and the one you are using isn't supported by Firefox.

Use a library instead.

e.g. [moment](https://momentjs.com/):

```
const date = moment('Oct 20, 2020 00:00:00:00', 'MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss:SS')
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using a library? Does a certain format get supported in all popular browsers?

Comment: You can write a custom parser yourself … but using a library means you don't have to do the work and can expect it to be robust and well tested.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You were correct and moment seems to have things working on FireFox! I'll mark this as the answer

Comment: moment is a bit overkill, can you not just use a simple format like `new Date(2020, 9, 20)`?

Comment: @albert_anthony6—of course you don't need a library, writing a function to parse a single format is trivial, maybe 3 lines of code. Writing a parser that accepts a format and string is somewhat more work, but still not particularly difficult. Just tedious (and there are many good, small, efficient parser and formatting libraries to chose from).

Comment: I wouldn't how to write such a function myself so for that reason, I went with the moment library